# What is the most efficient way of updating data in a MySQL table using Python avoiding loops?

Tags: python, mysql, dictionary

What is the best way to format data?

Here is the background :

I am using [nameparser](http://code.google.com/p/python-nameparser/) to parse a name the best way possible. I built a wrapper that calls the nameparser and then stores the parsed name in the database (MySQL).

What would be the most efficient approach in this case? Following is my approach.

1. Step 1 : call nameparser (provide tablename, id, name, first,
   middle, last, suffix).
2. Step 2 : Store the parsed (returned) name in
   a dict of this form in memory (I am parsing relatively small names
   set - say 20,000 names). `{id:{'first':'John', 'middle':'V',
   'last':'Doe', 'suffix':''}`
3. Step 3 : Store the dict in the MySQL
   table with one query? (Not sure if it is possible with the data
   structure described in Step 2.

Here is my code :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from nameparser import HumanName

import time

cursor = db.cursor()


def name(table, id, name, first, middle, last, suffix):

    cursor.execute('SELECT `' + id + '`,`' + name + '` FROM `' + table
                   + '` WHERE `' + name + '` IS NOT NULL AND ' + id
                   + ' IS NOT NULL')

    numrows = int(cursor.rowcount)
    namelist = []
    namelist = cursor.fetchall()

    for record in namelist:
        parsed = HumanName(record[1])
        parsed.capitalize()
        mydict[int(record[0])] = {
            'first': str(parsed.first),
            'middle': str(parsed.middle),
            'last': str(parsed.last),
            'suffix': str(parsed.suffix),
            }   

mydict = {}

starttime = time.time()

split = name('NamesToParse','id','name','first','middle','last','suffix')
print mydict
print time.time() - starttime
```

Please suggest the best way of storing the data in the MySQL table. This is what I have so far and I still have to loop through each record. I am wondering if there is a way to `update` the existing table rather than having to create a temp table first and then updating the original table in one go? Hope I made sense.

```
for id, val in mydict.items():

    sorted_keys = sorted(map(str, val.keys()))
    sorted_vals = map(encoding, [val[mydict] for mydict in sorted_keys])  # sorted by keys
    formatted = ', '.join(["'%s'"] * len(sorted_vals))
    db.execute("""insert into NamesToParseOut(%s) values (%s)""" % (', '.join(sorted_keys), formatted), sorted_vals)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I will take the List of tuples approach and insert in a temp table first followed by updating them with the original table. The time savings are amazing. I feel dictionary is an overkill for this task.

```
mylistoftuples.append((int(record[0]), str(parsed.first),str(parsed.middle),str(parsed.last),str(parsed.suffix)))

cursor.executemany("""insert into NamesToParseOut(id, first, middle, last, suffix) values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""", mylistoftuples)
```